# When sharing the Eyes of Night darkvision, does a creature needs to always be 10 feet close to the cleric to be granted the benefits?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, vision-and-light

The Eyes of Night feature from the Twilight Domain Cleric, introduced in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* pg. 34, grants darkvision to the cleric:

> You can see through the deepest gloom. You have darkvision out to a range of 300 feet.

It also allows the cleric to share this darkvision with willing creatures:

> As an action, you can magically share the darkvision of this feature with willing creatures you can see **within 10 feet of you**, up to a number of creatures equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of one creature). **The shared darkvision lasts for 1 hour**. [...]

It's clear that the creature needs to be within 10 feet of the cleric for him to use an action to share the darkvision. **But once shared, does that creature needs to be within 10 feet of the cleric to be granted the benefits of the darkvision from Eyes of Night?** Since the sharing has a duration 1 hour I'm wondering what if a creature that wandered far away from the cleric would still be granted this benefit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The darkvision stays for its duration.

This works similarly to a spell's range and effects. For example, the spell *darkvision* has a range of touch and a duration of 8 hours, but this just means the target of the spell must be withing range when you give it the effect. The same logic applies to the Eyes of the Night feature: you can target a number of creatures you can see within 10 feet of you, and these benefits last for 1 hour.

If an effects needs you to stay close to its source or beacon, the game will tell you. This is the case of continuous area effects, such as auras, which specify that a creature gains certain benefits while withing that area / within that distance from the origin.
Another similar case is *Mordenkainen's Faithful Hound*, which specifies that the spell ends if you move more than a 100 feet away from the spectral hound.