# What happen if a Twilight Domain Cleric that shared his darkvision becomes unconscious or dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, vision-and-light

The Eyes of Night feature from the Twilight Domain Cleric, introduced in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything pg. 34, grants darkvision to the cleric:

> You can see through the deepest gloom. You have darkvision out to a range of 300 feet.

It also allows the cleric to share this darkvision with willing creatures:

> As an action, you can magically share the darkvision of this feature with willing creatures you can see within 10 feet of you, up to a number of creatures equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of one creature). The shared darkvision lasts for 1 hour. [...]

But the description of the feature does not state what would happen if the cleric becomes unconscious or dies, only that it last for 1 hour.
I can think of some interpretations for those scenarios:

1. The cleric already used his action to share his darkvision, so he does not need to do anything and the sharing will last for the duration, regardless of what happen to the cleric.
2. Since it is **your (the cleric)** darkvision, if the cleric goes unconscious that cleric still have the darkvision and the feature, so it's still shared. But if the cleric dies, a corpse does not have such a feature, so the sharing is cut off.
3. An unconscious creature cannot use its features, so, even though the cleric shared when he was conscious, once he becomes unconscious the sharing is canceled. Naturally, the same goes in the case if he dies.

Personally I think the second scenario is the more appropriate, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Is there any official rule that could help to determine what would happen in this cases?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### If something would happen, the feature would clearly state so.

The Eyes of Night feature simply specifies that it lasts for 1 hour. If something would have happened if the cleric were to fall unconscious or dead, or some under other circumstances, the feature would tell you. This is the case in your scenario #1.

Some examples I can think of are the Barbarian's Rage feature (specifying other special conditions), and the Druid's Wild Shape feature:

> It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven't attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then.

> You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die.

Other effects that would end earlier than normal if you die or become incapacitated are concentration spells, but the Eyes of Night feature simply lasts for 1 hour, without the need for the cleric to sustain it further for that duration.

Comment: I think you would make a stronger argument if you were to refer to class features or other features that affect other characters instead of those that only impact the user. Paladin auras come to mind as do Path of the Storm Herald features.

Comment: Both of those examples refer to "aura effects". If you could help me by providing a feature that is not an "aura" to use as an example I'd apreciate it. We have already estabilished that this is not an aura effect in this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180002/when-sharing-the-eyes-of-night-darkvision-does-a-creature-needs-to-always-be-10